# Video and Audio stream in Python pipe to ffmpeg

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg

Raw video from Python pipe is converted to udp stream using FFMPEG is working correctly using following code:

```
command = [ 'ffmpeg',
            '-y', # (optional) overwrite output file if it exists
            '-r', '25', # frames per second
            '-i', '-', # The imput comes from a pipe
            '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
            '-r', '25',
            '-c:v', 'copy',
            '-f', 'mpegts', 
            'udp://ip:port'
        ]
devl  = open(os.devnull, 'w')
file_name = '/tmp/file.txt'
err1 = open(file_name, 'w')
pipe  = sp.Popen( command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=devl, stderr=err1)
```

But when audio stream also coming in same python pipe, how i should change the program to get both audio and video stream to udp stream.

Comment: Is your input also an `mpegts` stream?

Comment: @jamieguinan yes i think so. And also when i write to an mp4 file video works fine. but audio not coming.

Comment: In your example, remove '-an' and add '-c:a', 'copy'.

Comment: @jamieguinan ithanks. but I tried that too. it is still not working.